# The function of "might"

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, verbs

What is the function of this "might?"

> I am from Niger. People there don't dare to dream big. But I thought I ***might*** dream big.

Answer (score 2):

It essentially means

> There was a time in the past when I thought that in the future it could be possible for me to dream big.

Where *it could be possible for me to* could be replaced with *I might*.

He's reminiscing to a time when he had hopes of achieving big dreams. Whether or not he succeeded at this isn't determined by this sentence.

Comment: Could it also mean "I thought I could allow myself to dream big, even though most didn't"? Like the "might" of "She asked if she might stay a bit longer?"

Comment: @kih1930 I think it's more "I thought I could *be able to* dream big" than *allow myself to*, but beyond that, yes. "I thought I would have the chance to dream big and succeed, even though others didn't."

Comment: So I could say, "I thought I might stay here a bit longer" in response to "Please go home. You are overstaying your visit."?

Comment: @kih - I think your alternate interpretation is also valid. In fact, that was how I interpreted the sentence. Essentially, it's the same as "But I thought I might [dare to] dream big." Without any further context, though, we can't say for sure, we can only suggest possible interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically speaking, OP's sentence is ambiguous. The two possible meanings are exemplified by...

> 1: My cousin was having a party, and [I asked my mother if I **might** go](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20asked%20my%20mother%20if%20I%20might%20go%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).
>    2: My cousin was having a party, and [I thought I **might** go](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20asked%20my%20mother%20if%20I%20might%20go%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22I%20thought%20I%20might%20go%22&tbm=bks).

In #1, *might* implies ***permission***, but in #2 it simply implies ***possibility*** - which, according to context, could be anything from a low probability to a firm intention.

---

In practice it's probably academic to debate which of the two senses applies in OP's case. I doubt that even in Niger anyone has formal authority to either permit or prevent others from "dreaming big", so it's really a matter of whether ***circumstances*** make it possible to have high aspirations. We can probably assume the speaker *would* dream big if it were "possible" (whatever that might mean in this context).

It's Off Topic writing advice, but I'd also add that OP's three sentences are inherently contradictory to me. *(I'm a dog. Dogs are quadrupeds. I have two legs.)* So I'd suggest *"...don't **usually** dare to dream big".*